# Why isn't my custom animation working correctly?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

My custom @keyframes animation is not working the way it should.

There is no gap between `Block 1` and `Block 2` when rotating but there is a small gap between `Block 2` and `Block 3`, `Block 3` and `Block 4`, and, `Block 4` and `Block 1`.

I cant understand why there is a gap between the above listed block or why there is no block between Block 1 and Block 2. What should I do to remove the gaps, I want it to look like a box without the gaps.

Any other advice on the code is also appreciated.
Below is the code.

```css
.main {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.main>div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2em;
  transition: 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.child1 {
  background: red;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  animation: animate1 8s infinite;
}

.child2 {
  background: blue;
  transform-origin: top;
  animation: animate2 8s infinite;
}

.child3 {
  background: yellow;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  animation: animate3 8s infinite;
}

.child4 {
  background: green;
  transform-origin: top;
  animation: animate4 8s infinite;
}


/*.main:hover .child1{
 transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
}

.main:hover .child2{
 transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
}*/

@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child1">Block 1</div>
  <div class="child2">Block 2!</div>
  <div class="child3">Block 3</div>
  <div class="child4">Block 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would try spin the whole thing, well maybe you can get some ideas here: https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-cube.php

Comment: Wow! that's some nice styling would definitely check it out. Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you are animating the `transform-origin` between states, you should avoid this by adding more states in order to rapidly change the `transform-origin`. By changing the `transform-origin` you logically change how the element rotate and you create an unwanted movement that create the gap you see.

**Why you don't see it between block 1 and block 2?**

Simply because if you look at the first states of both elements you will see no change on transform-origin so there is no movement that will create the gap unlike the other states:

```css
.main {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.main>div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2em;
  transition: 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.child1 {
  background: red;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  animation: animate1 8s infinite;
}

.child2 {
  background: blue;
  transform-origin: top;
  animation: animate2 8s infinite;
}

.child3 {
  background: yellow;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  animation: animate3 8s infinite;
}

.child4 {
  background: green;
  transform-origin: top;
  animation: animate4 8s infinite;
}

@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  25.5% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  75.5% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  0.5% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  50.5% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  0.5% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  25.5% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  75.5% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(0%) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child1">Block 1</div>
  <div class="child2">Block 2!</div>
  <div class="child3">Block 3</div>
  <div class="child4">Block 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but wouldn't adding more states will affect the animation timing a little? @Temani Afif

Comment: @JasbindarSingh no it won't ;) the idea behind is to prevent the animaion of transform-origin, so I simply add another state to change it rapidply and keep the transform as it is, so only transform-origin is affect then everything else is good as you can notice :)

Comment: yes I got your point, I was just making sure if the timing changes or not. And thanks for the explanation. :) @TemaniAfif